# How to compress the CSS and JS in Moodle

Tags: moodle

The moodle site takes 12 seconds to load the login page, if 10 concurrent users access the site.

Is there any possibility to compress the CSS and Java script through Moodle admin end?

Answer (score 0):

You could minify your CSS (cssminifier.com/)

And JS (http://jscompress.com/)

I dont think there is anything native to Moodle to do this.